# Can Bootsfaces be used with Richfaces?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, compatibility, bootsfaces

I have a web application with the following:

- JSF 2.2.6
- Java 1.7
- Tomcat 8
- Richfaces 4.5.7
- Omnifaces 2.2

I would like to enhance the look and feel of the web app to use Bootsfaces.  I have added Bootsfaces jar to my project (via .ivy) and rebuilt.

Before even updating the first web page to use Bootsfaces in the project I wanted to see if there were any conflicts after adding the Bootsfaces jar.  It seems there is.  I am getting the following errors shown in Firebug:

- ReferenceError: jsf is not defined
- TypeError: RichFaces.ui is undefined

Does anyone know whether Bootsfaces works with Richfaces and if so could they kindly provide a link with migration steps to follow?

Comment: Some how this question near to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213655/jsf-and-primefaces-or-bootstrap-or-bootsfaces-or-both  but i think no will able to answer your exact question ,reason is that very less people are using Richfaces also Richfaces is maintenance project from last couple of years .

Comment: Thanks Subodh.  I found out today that Richfaces is closing down as of June 2016.  So I'm currently looking at migrating from Richfaces to PrimeFaces.  Hopefully it is not too painful.   After that, I will take another look at Bootsfaces.

Comment: With Primefaces you can easily integrate BootsFaces ,i dont know whats your project we migrated our project from Richfaces to Primefaces in 2009 when i heard about this. I dont know how much issues for you.

Comment: thanks again, it's a medium sized application with one major search/data table, so I think it's worth the effort.  I also hear that PrimeFaces either currently (or will) support custom AngularJS.

Comment: Primefaces already started PrimeNG which is currently 0.8 version .Let me know if u need further help.

Comment: thanks, if you summarise your comments above as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108135/discussion-between-subodh-joshi-and-user1746582).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, we, the BootsFaces team, do not support RichFaces. We strive for compatibility with PrimeFaces, OmniFaces, AngularFaces and - if possible - ButterFaces. Neither RichFaces nor ICEFaces are on our list.

However, if someone were to join our team in order to support RichFaces, they'd certainly be welcome!

Comment: thanks Stephan, that makes my decision to move to PrimeFaces a lot easier :)